# Print a word in my code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 2 numbers in Javascript and using the below code which was given at the stack overflow website.

I want to print the output of the file as `RESULT =`. It now just shows the result without any wordings before it. Could you please let me know how to display the result as `RESULT = $result$`

```
    <html>
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>Enter first number:
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">Enter second number:
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var y = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        var x = +y + +z;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Java is NOT JavaScript! 2) What have you tried? 3) I'd start finding which line assigns the display value of result in the HTML..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

to

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'RESULT=' +x;
```

As @Marcell Fülöp has pointed out, this is actually javascript and not Java. There should be heaps of information online to get to know the two.

Just to break it down a bit, `document.getElementById("demo")` gets for you the element (in this case a paragraph) in the html document that has an id of `demo`. The `.innerHTML =` is letting you put what ever value you want inside of that `demo`element.

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer. Sorry i have one last doubt. I also want a multiline print. I am trying to use '\n' to print the next string in the next line but unable to do so. Could you please help  `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Result = '+ x + '\n This is how we got';` . I want string "This is how we got" in the next line

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Result = '+ x + '<br> This is how we got';` ([more info on <br>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)). So any html tags you put in `.innerHTML` gets rendered as HTML.